# Jerky Lerp motion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this `IEnumerator` to move my player to a specific place on a game board tile after he has reached that tile. Here is the code, its really simple.

```
  IEnumerator LerpToPlayerSpot(Vector3 newPosition, float time)
    {
        float elapsedTime = 0;
        Vector3 startingPos = transform.position;
getInPosFlag = true;
        while (elapsedTime < time)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startingPos, newPosition, (elapsedTime / time));
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

    }
```

The problem I'm having is that after reaching the correct position the player seems to jerk around a bit before settling into place. I remember fixing this in some other project by implementing my own approximation, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution.

Edit. I fixed it. the `getInPosFlag` should be set before the while loop. because I was setting it after the while loop the co-routine got called one or two more times than it was needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
(elapsedTime / time)
```

to

```
Math.Min((elapsedTime / time), 1)
```

if time is not a Time.deltaTime multiple (time % Time.deltaTime != 0) then you're exceeding the Lerp range (0,1).

With Math.Min you will restrict the output to one.

Comment: Thanks. using Math.Min did nothing for me, but I had forgotten to multiple the param I'm passing to the co-routine by Time.deltaTime

Comment: after further  testing the jerky motion is still there, the jerks are no less prominent.

Comment: Can you define "jerky"? it fails at the end? on between?

Comment: I doesnt fail. it reached the correct pos and then it goes back and forth between that pos for a bit.

Comment: can the problem not be on that function but outside? maybe your object is not correctly placed outside that function?

Comment: Also, is your distances very small? maybe you're facing a float calculation error.

Comment: The target pos is 1.5x 0.7y for example and the player ends up on 1.53x 0.76y. This is a acceptable error. However I can figure out why the Lerp does not stop when these numbers are met. It just jiggles back and forth for a couple more frames and then stops.

Comment: With the Math.Min it can't go beyond newPosition, if it's moving further then it should be from external code (unless the Lerp code has any bug, you can always create your own Lerp function as it's really basic -> value1 + (value2 - value1) * amount).